# 'Pause Script Execution' in Chrome DevTools not working as expected

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-debugger

On my lynda.com course, my instructor says that the "Pause Script Execution" button will "pause *at the first execution* of any JavaScript whatsoever."

[image]

He goes on to demonstrate:

1. Presses the pause button.
2. Then clicks to close an image gallery.
3. After clicking the close button, the debugger pauses the script and takes him to the line of code the script paused on, where the click to close the image gallery was handled.

However, when I press this button it simply *pauses everything immediately*. I can't click on anything in order to pause the script at the execution of any JavaScript, as the instructor does.

My alternative solution was to use an Event Listener Breakpoint for click events, so I was able to do what I wanted in this scenario. But I'm just wondering why the pause button isn't working as it is in this tutorial I'm watching. Anyone understand why?

**Update**: It was because I had Chrome React Devtools extension enabled and that was interfering. I disabled it and restarted chrome and it works now.

Comment: It just means the site runs something periodically e.g. in setTimeout, setInterval, etc. The event listener breakpoint is the correct universal solution here as well as DOM modification breakpoints.

Comment: @wOxxOm I thought that was my issue, however I went back to the tutorial and tried it on the same site he used it on (an html file I downloaded that goes along with the tutorial) and it still doesn't work as expected even on the same file as him.

Comment: Doesn't seem possible with the touch bar, will need an external keyboard to access the function keys at the same time.